# Putting my RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView misplaces all the items in the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

Thank a lot for your help and attention.

This is how my Activity looks like before I put the RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView:

[image]

Still I need to work on it, but the Buttons, the EditTexts and the Views are at their place.

---

Now, if I put the RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView, all the positions of the items get messed up,

this is the (undesired) result

[image]

Please how do I go about this?

Here is my XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgland"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MenuActivity" >
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dip"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/white_bg" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/bikenumber"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/getbikebutton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/hint_getbike"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/getbikebutton"
    style="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
    android:text="@string/menu_getbikebuttontext" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGoToMyLoc"
    style="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
    android:text="@string/menu_text_near_me" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGoToThisLoc"
    style="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonGoToMyLoc"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="@string/menu_text_address" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
    android:text="@string/menu_title"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/locAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/menu_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/locAddressCity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/locAddress"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/menu_hint_city"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add [`android:fillViewport="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android%3afillViewport) to your ScrollView code as follows :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_margin="20dip"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@android:color/white" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/bikenumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/getbikebutton"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Get Bikes"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/getbikebutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:text="FindBikes" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonGoToMyLoc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:text="NearMe" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonGoToThisLoc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/buttonGoToMyLoc"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Near Address" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/locAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Addresss"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/locAddressCity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/locAddress"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Address City"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

`ScrollView` comes with `LinearLayout` and it works with only direct child inside `ScrollView`. You can put all the component inside that `LinearLayout`.So if you want any layout inside `ScrollView` then you should first put `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView` and put all your components inside that `LinearLayout`.

Comment: can you give me the full screen design so that i can design the entire screen for you?

Comment: this works Imran!!! You are great!!! Please I do not understand what is the difference, what was I doing wrong

Comment: scrollview comes with linearlayout and it works with only one layout inside scrollview you can put all the component inside that linear layout.So if you want any layout inside scrollview then you should first put linearlayout inside scrollview and put all your components inside that linear layout

Comment: This is a perfect example of why code only answers are not helpful. @ImranBetara please edit your answer to include the explanation in it.

Comment: -1 for code-only answer. I see you have an explanation in your comments. Please add that to your answer so this post will be more useful to future visitors.

Comment: I have removed my downvote this time. Please try and avoid code-only answers in the future by including explanations and/or helpful links.

Comment: thank you @codeMagic i will remember that in future thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:fillViewport="true"` tag in your `ScrollView`. I think it may solve your problem. Just like this code below:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
```

If you want to know more about this, you could check this out [ScrollView’s handy trick](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Comment: which id? Could you please clarify it little bit.

Comment: sorry Sharif, I meant it ("thank you Sharif, but it does not work"), I edited the comment

Comment: Hi @LisaAnne I think something is wrong. Instead of this  android:layout_below="@+id/view1" for getbikebutton could you please use android:layout_above="@id/view1"

Comment: And please re-check your code. I think it should work.

Comment: I think the problem inside RelativeLayout. I think you could fix it yourself. Thank you Lisa Anne.

Answer (score 0):

Sharif is right, however that will not always be enough. The inner layout (the only child of the ScrollView) should never use match_parent because this essentially means it will be as large as the ScrollView but never bigger - The whole point is that the inner layout will be larger than what fits on the screen, and thus larger than the ScrollView. The relative layout should either have it's height to wrap_content, or be given a fixed size in DP, depending on your needs.

Combine this with Sharif's answer and it should work out for you.

This worked for me in terms of scrolling and layout height, however it your relative layout is a bit messed up - Why not use a simple Linear Layout instead and just lay out the buttons/texts one after the other? It looks like an easier method to achieve the same appearance.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

   ... content ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank you nitzanj, I ave tried adding vandroid:fillViewport="true"` and setting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on the RelativeLayout, but nothing changes :-(((

Comment: I just tested your xml and it works for me with fillViewport and wrap_content so I'm not sure why it's failing for you. What happens when you set the relative layout height to 1500dp or so? Works as expected?

Comment: Hi nitzanj, I have tried setting android:layout_height any size, but no changes :-((( if your XML works, please could you post it? Thanks! LISA